# Prevent complex button from breaking into parts

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery UI to create a button with a drop-down that is placed inside a dialog:

http://jsfiddle.net/ph5Jw/6/

When I resize the width of the dialog to its minimal setting, the second part of the button jumps on the next line. How do I prevent it from wrapping -- I want the button parts to never break apart.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify [white-space: nowrap;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/white-space) on the container.

[Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ph5Jw/8/)